# Can we able to create two instance of log4j

Tags: java, jboss, log4j

Can we able to create two instance of log4j in class one to write in file and another in jdbcadapter?

```
// one to write log in console
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass()); 

// write in database within one class 
Logger log1 = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

My jdbc adapter is
    
        
        
        
        
        
    
    
        
    
My file adapter is
    
        
        
        
        
        
            
        
    
I wan to Logger instance log for File anmd Logger instant log1 for jdbc.

Comment: In your sample tow instance is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `log4j` there are various `Appenders` available, with descriptive names, such as `FileAppender, ConsoleAppender, SocketAppender, SyslogAppender, NTEventLogAppender and even SMTPAppender`. Multiple Appenders can be attached to any Logger, so it's possible to log the same information to multiple outputs; for example to a file locally and to a socket listener on another computer.

Moreover if want to write logs to different outputs according to the level then you could try [Log to appender by level](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/LogToAppenderByLevel).

Comment: My question is i want to write some internal logical process in file system and my request and response in database. I know that there adapter like as given above. In single class i want write one in File and another one in database.

Answer (score 1):

This only works in case you give the second logger a different name. Else both variables will contain the same instance. For example:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
Logger log1 = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName() + ".db");
```

Then you got two separated loggers.

Comment: Ok @Nitram how you will write adapter for this

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that creates the instances (or returns the same cached one), but even if it does, it will have the same appender configuration (as the same class name is used for the category).

You can get two different loggers with different category names:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass()); 

Logger log1 = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()+".extra");
```

Where they log to is configured in log4j.properties.

Also, you can have the same logger log to multiple appenders, depending on filters such as priority. So unless you have complex logic in your code as to what to log where, you can just use one logger and it can still go to both file and database.

Comment: How to write adapter for log1 instance separately where as it will not any log for the name "log "